# Hotspot markers in Google Streetview

Tags: android, css, google-street-view

I am building an android app and I am trying to figure out a way to place custom markers in Google Streetview, something like *hotspots* that display images when clicked and move along with the camera so that they go off screen if necessary. I have no experience at all, so I would at least understand where to start studying.

Would it be possible with CSS position properties?

Edit: I am searching for a way to locate them in street view mode, not in map mode.

Answer (score 0):

Marco! Work with markers is very simple. For drag-drop marker you should override methods onMarkerDragStart, onMarkerDrag, onMarkerDragEnd. All click on marker call infoWindow. So, you can set your InfoWindowAdapter to map and implement your code logical here.
 For concurrent moving camera with marker (right me understand?). Unlike ios version of google map, you can catch only final position of your camera (analoge idleCameraPosition on ios). So, i think you have to move marker first, and after it set camera to marker position

The best way to understand simple things of android google map is https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup

Comment: thank you for your reply :D, but unfortunately i think you mean locating a marker on map. What i'm searching for is a way to locate interactive markers in the street view mode.